# c# sqlite stack evaluation

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have strange error in function `FindDocuments` in lines

```
var value = command.ExecuteScalar();

using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
```

in debug mode `command` all properties contains the same exception
"Impossible to calculate expression, because frame of machine code situated at the top of call stack"

What can cause such error? I have no idea why it does not work.

Singleton:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private static SQLiteConnection connection;

    public static SQLiteConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (connection == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (connection == null)
                    {
                        connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"data source=D:\informServicesDocs.db3");
                    }
                }
            }
            if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

Function with problem:

```
public IEnumerable<InformServiceBriefInfo> FindDocuments(InformServiceSearchInfo criteria, int limit, ref int page, out int count)
    {   
            var query = string.Format(@"SELECT *       
                      FROM [BriefDocument]
                        {0}
                      ORDER BY [CreatedDate] DESC", whereStr);

            string queryCount = string.Format("SELECT COUNT([Id]) FROM [BriefDocument] {0}", whereStr);

            List<InformServiceBriefInfo> docs = new List<InformServiceBriefInfo>();
            var con = Singleton.Connection;
            {
                using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(con))
                {
                    command.CommandText = queryCount;
                    var value = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    count = (value == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : (int)(long)value;

                    command.CommandText = query;
                    if (limit > 0)
                    {
                        if (page > count / limit)
                            page = count / limit;
                        int offset = page * limit;
                        command.CommandText += string.Format(" LIMIT {0} OFFSET {1}", limit, offset);
                    }

                    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var doc = ReadBriefDocument(reader);
                            docs.Add(doc);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return docs;
    }
```

Comment: Does this happen when you explictly pause the debugger during `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteScalar`?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, It sounds strange but when i am placing break point on `SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()` visual studio throws exception context switch deadlock.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, i noticed that this problem occures when size of database is increasing.